# Meteor - use route parameter as part of a DOM query

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to take a route parameter and use it to perform a click event on a DOM element. But, onBeforeAction is called before the DOM is ready. How can I accomplish this?

**JS**

```
onBeforeAction: function(){

  var param = this.params;

  if ( param ) {
    var $tab = $('.nav-tabs__menu--' + param.setting );

    // wont work, $tab will be undefined
    $tab.click()
  } 
  this.next()
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `onAfterAction` ?

Comment: How about `var param = typeof(this.params) != "undefined"?true:false;`

Comment: @saimeunt Derp. onAfterAction worked. I swear I tried that.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM has not finished rendering at this point. Try moving this code into the 'action' or 'onAfterAction' callback.

Alternatively, you could execute this code within your template's onRendered() callback and pass the parameter through the 'data' function:

**Iron Router**

```
data: function(){
    return this.params;
}
```

**Template Callback**

```
Template.myTemplateName.onRendered(function(){
    var params = this.data;
    $('.nav-tabs__menu--' + params.setting ).click();
});
```